# Failed to generate/retrieve public encryption key for reCAPTCHA flow

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

i tried to disable the reCAPTCHA flow on my android app by following these steps.

> remove reCaptcha by Enabling the Android Device Verification API in
> Your Project on google cloud console. You can do that by Adding Your
> Project there.
>
> After that you should also add SHA-256 key in Your Firebase Project in
> Project Setting.
>
> Now there will be no reCaptchaa to verify to that your are not a
> robot.

but it didnt work for me, instead of that i getting error while genrating OTP

```
Exception encountered during crypto setup:
Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

KeysetManager failed to initialize - unable to get Public key

Could not generate an encryption key for reCAPTCHA - cancelling flow

Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred. [ Failed to generate/retrieve public encryption key for reCAPTCHA flow. ]]- calling backend without app verification
```

i'm getting this error while testing the app with Redmi note 5 pro,

while Samsung A20 and one plus9 are showing reCAPTCHA flow but getting OTP as the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had following error for authenticating with twitter using Firebase:

```
Failed to generate/retrieve public encryption key for Generic IDP flow.
```

The solution was to set the following in the manifest:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

Apparently, this happens/required because after uninstalling the application if you allow backup then your public encryption key is left behind but if you are installing a changed/new version of the app then the retrieved key (from backup) could not be decrypted, but if you disallow backup and reinstall the app then the key gets removed and then regenerated.

After applying above change to the manifest I then reinstalled the app then uninstalled it (to effectively remove the previously backed up key), then installed it fresh again and worked.

Answer (score 1):

okay I found the solution for this problem, need to follow a few steps more in order to disable the reCAPTCHA flow

In Android, the solution was to enable agree the terms and conditions of the SafetyNet in FireBase Project settings under App Check tab.

Just Click on the App that you want to enable the SafetyNet on and a new checkbox will appear. Agree the term and vola the error is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the project in firebase and re-create it with the same package name works for me

Comment: This is the solution, even though it might seem unlikely.
Delete the app (not the project) and re-create it.